How to Implement an object pool in Java that does not create garbage as it grows?
My Java application has excessive garbage collection due to its frequent object creation and disposal, so I want to implement an object pool to reuse objects and reduce GC overhead. How can I design a garbage-free object pool that dynamically adjusts its size (without creating garbage) based on application load? Can you provide an example implementation or guidance for pooling strategies, especially for pool growth?

Question is too broad for [so]. Rather than implementing your own try searching for existing pooling libraries from trusted sources. If you still want to implement one yourself then try first then ask about specific issues.

@aled The specific issue is how to grow without producing garbage

You should share your code for the object pool explaining why it generates too much garbage collection. [ask] provides guidance on how to make good questions for [so].

Garbage and garbage collection is usually more efficient in Java than pooling.  Let garbage happen.

@LouisWasserman While the Java allocator might be better performing than pooling, the issue is that you have no control over when the collection occurs - essentially all the deallocation occur at once, which can really slow down or stop your application.  In some apps, that slow down / stop can cause you to fall very far behind when processing events, and might keep you from ever catching up.  In a trading application, that could mean you're never making decisions with up-to-date data, which could be disastrous.

@TraderJenny  Assuming you're the author (or can edit) the code for the class C you want to pool, create a new type, Linkable which has T getNext() and setNext(T) methods, and then make C implement Linkable.  Now you can make a class Pool<T extends Linkable> which essentially maintains a chain of Linkable and has a method T borrow() which returns the item at the end of the list, and release(T) which puts that item at the end of the list.

@TraderJenny  Growing without making garbage is straight forward with the approach I outlined in the other comment.  Shrinking w/o making garbage is impossible.  Usually, it is good enough to never shrink the pool.  If you need to, the best is if you have a "cleanup" event, where you can throw some items off the pool, and then call System.gc().  You'd schedule the cleanup event for a time where you expect the system to be non-busy.

@TraderJenny If you can't change the code of class C, it is a bit more complex.  Essentially, you need to make your own Node class, which has a Node getNext() and setNext(Node).  You then need to maintain two chains of Nodes.  One is your "object pool" the other is the empty Nodes.  When you borrow a T, you take the last Node on from the pool chain, and move it to the empty chain (and return its T).  When you return a T to the pool, you take the last Node of the empty chain, sets its object the T you are returning, and then add that Node to the end of the pool chain.

The best data structure to use is a native array due to its better cache locality. The key challenge is to allow it to grow without generating garbage. This can be achieved by storing the previous array in a SoftReference:
int newSize = int (growthFactor * this.array.length);
E[] oldArray = this.array;
this.array = (E[]) new Object[newSize];
// copy from oldArray to this.array (if necessary)
// nullify any object left on oldArray (if necessary)
oldArrays.add(new SoftReference<E[]>(oldArray));

You can try implementing this approach yourself as an exercise, or you can use CoralPool, which is an open-source garbage-free solution optimized for performance. For a deeper dive into writing garbage-free Java code, check out this video.
On a side note, using java.util.LinkedList is not ideal because, like many other Java collections, it generates a significant amount of garbage. This creates a contradiction: you’re trying to minimize garbage using an object pool, but the pool itself contributes to garbage creation. Clearly, that's not an efficient approach. Run the code below to observe how much garbage it generates:
final LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
    
final Object object = new Object();
final Random random = new Random();
    
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    
for(int i = 0; i < 50_000; i++) {
    int toAdd = random.nextInt(1_000) + 1;
    int toRemove = random.nextInt(1_000) + 1;
    for(int x = 0; x < toAdd; x++) list.add(object);
    for(int x = 0; x < toRemove; x++) if (!list.isEmpty()) list.removeLast();
}

long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
System.out.println("List size: " + list.size() + " after " + time + " millis"); 

 $ java -verbose:gc -cp . TestLinkedList 

[0.003s][info][gc] Using G1
[0.034s][info][gc] GC(0) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 25M->1M(388M) 0.796ms
[0.043s][info][gc] GC(1) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 29M->1M(388M) 1.587ms
[0.060s][info][gc] GC(2) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 61M->2M(388M) 2.989ms
[0.082s][info][gc] GC(3) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 78M->3M(388M) 4.149ms
[0.107s][info][gc] GC(4) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 111M->1M(820M) 1.293ms
[0.149s][info][gc] GC(5) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 137M->2M(820M) 2.541ms
List size: 38609 after 166 millis 


When you grow the array you will have to copy a lot of elements from the old array to the new array. I know you can use System.arraycopy for better performance, but it will still be a good overhead.

Depending on how you implement it, you can end up with an empty array with nothing to copy over.

@JoasCoder The GCs that object pools help eliminate are those that occur because there isn't enough memory to satisfy an allocation request.  Making the old array non-reachable, vs. softly-reachable will have zero effect on this - we will exhaust the heap at the same rate, and in either case the old arrays will need to be collected.  I could see maybe some benefit if we reused an old array at some point, but I actually don't see that in the CoralPool code.  What am I missing?

You can use a linked list, that does not have a fixed size. You can just keep adding nodes to it as your pool grows. Something like that:
public class ObjectPool<T> {

    private final LinkedList<T> pool = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Creator<T> creator;

    public ObjectPool(Creator<T> creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    public synchronized T acquire() {
        if (pool.isEmpty()) {
            return creator.create();
        }
        return pool.removeLast();
    }

    public synchronized void release(T obj) {
        pool.addLast(obj);
    }

    public interface Creator<T> {
        T create();
    }
}


You should probably call removeLast() instead of removeFirst() to reuse the same object as much as possible

Have you considered concurrency in this implementation?

@aled I added the synchronized keyword. @SpeedChaser => Good point! I changed to removeLast().

Just adding synchronized is not a solution for concurrency. Try testing it under concurrent load and see if it doesn't get corrupted and causes dead locks.

@DuncG You are correct, bad refactoring :)

@PhillipBorge If you take a look at LinkedList's implementation, you'll see that the list's "structure" is a bunch of LinkedList.Node objects. Is is these Nodes which hold the actual objects of type E you put on the list.   So what's the issue?  When you call LinkedList.removeLast(), to acquire an E from the pool, you're essentially making the last Node garbage.    So while you've avoided of making garbage of E objects, you're making garbage of Nodes.  If you're the author of E, a much better approach is to make E contain a reference to a 'next E' and maintain the list yourself.
